# Insert image blob into MySQL database using python and retrieve the blob to display image using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where we are storing some images in the database as a blob using python and we want to access the image blobs from database via php to display those images. We are using Python3 and MySQL. We are storing imagedata to the database as a blob in the following way:

```
import MySQLdb
import base64

dbConnector = MySQLdb.connect(host=host_name, user=user_name, passwd=password, db=db_name)
cursor = dbConnector.cursor()

with open("Path/to/image.jpeg", 'rb') as f:
    imagedata = f.read()
imagedata = base64.b64encode(imagedata)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {} (image_data) VALUES (%s)".format(table_name), (imagedata,))

dbConnector.commit()
```

To display the images on webpage, we have tried using

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{image_data_retrieved_from_database}" height="60px"/>
```

but no images are being displayed. What are we doing wrong? What can we do to fix this?

Comment: A. is the file going in to the db? b. how are you extracting it via php (no code is shown here)

Comment: @IdontDownVote A. Yes, the file is going in the DB. I have checked that. B. I am not sure. I do not know php. My colleague is the one handling php. If you need the info, I will ask him.

Comment: This a pure php question, if the file is already in the db the whole python is finished. so wee need to see the php

Comment: @IdontDownVote Okay, thanks.

Comment: @IdontDownVote I just got the message that the code is working on the web server, but not on a local server. I will close this question for now. If I get any useful information later on, I will update here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The type of column "image_data" in the database was blob on local MySQL and mediumblob on web server. This was the root of images not being displayable since the image data was large for type blob.